# TextBox on ASP.Net website always reads null despite typing in a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am quite new to coding ASP.Net on Visual Studio so forgive me if this is a simple fix. I am creating a search bar for a therapist database that returns the database with the value that you have searched. However, when I type in a value that should work it always returns as null and shows the full database instead of the database that shows the searched values.

Here is the TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="179px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is my GetTherapists method in my DataLayer class that connects, receives, and returns the data that you have entered

```
public static dsTherapists GetTherapists(string Database, string strSearch)
{
    //Declare dataset, connection and data adapter objects
    dsTherapists DS2;
    OleDbConnection sqlConn;
    OleDbDataAdapter sqlDA;

    //Display all database entries if no text is in search field
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSearch))
    {
        //Initialize a connection to database
        sqlConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Database);

        //Populates sqlDA object with all data from tblTherapist
        sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblTherapist", sqlConn);

        //Populates the DS object
        DS2 = new dsTherapists();

        sqlDA.Fill(DS2.tblTherapist);

        //Returns populated DS object
        return DS2;
    }

    else if (strSearch.Length >= 1)
    {
        //Initialize a connection to database
        sqlConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Database);

        //Populates sqlDA object with all data from tblTherapist that
        sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblTherapist WHERE TherapistName LIKE '% "+ strSearch + " %' ", sqlConn);

        //Create an empty dataset
        DS2 = new dsTherapists();

        //Populate dataset from data adapter
        sqlDA.Fill(DS2.tblTherapist);

        //Returns populated DS object
        return DS2;
    }

    DS2 = new dsTherapists();

    return DS2;
}
```

}

Here is the .cs code that should be connecting the text from the text box and sending it to my DataLayer class

```
 public partial class ViewTherapistsSearched : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strSearch = Request["txtSearch"];

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dsTherapists myDataSet = new dsTherapists();
            myDataSet = DataLayer.GetTherapists(Server.MapPath("Persona.accdb"), strSearch);
            gvTherapist.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["tblTherapist"];
            gvTherapist.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should not have spaces between the % and your data. You are probably matching a lot more than you expect that way. Remove the spaces in your search string aftrer and before the % symbols. 

sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblTherapist WHERE TherapistName LIKE '%"+ strSearch + " %'", sqlConn);

Comment: Also, building out a SQL query like this is opening yourself up to SQL injection attack. At the very least, you need to make sure people don't put apostrophes in your search string (or remove them). Otherwise, someone could search for something with an apostrophe in it, and it'll end your search string and allow them to put whatever SQL code they want up to and including drop table.

Comment: Hi Lucas, welcome to SO! I suggest to use [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter) instead of building SQL query with string concating.